# Скрыть блок с возможностью обращения к нему

Tags: javascript, html

Есть блок с текстом и скрипт, который сохраняет текст в буфер обмена при нажатие на кнопку. Как убрать (скрыть) блок с текстом со страницы, но оставить возможность копировать текст при помощи скрипта?

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него пример кода, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Сложно ответить точно, не имея примера кода.
Однако простейший способ скрыть блок - применить к нему CSS правило `display:none`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить к блоку css свойство `visibility: hidden`, таким образом сделав его просто невидимым, как альтернативу `display: none`, которое является более жестким свойством.

В чем отличие между свойствами `display` и `visibility`:

- Свойство `visibility: hidden` означает, что элемент есть на
  странице, просто он невидимый, но место занимает. Получается как бы
  промежуток, равный его размерам.
- Свойство `display: none` означает, что элемент не будет появляется на
  странице вообще (хотя при этом он будет хранится в DOM как
  полноценный объект). Таким образом, он не будет занимать на экране
  места, и между предыдущим перед ним и следующим за ним элементами не образуется
  никакого промежутка.

В какой ситуации какое свойство применять - твое усмотрение.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать давать через скрипт нужному блоку класс hidden. Типа

```
$('.myClass').addClass('hidden');
```

Или же потом убирать

```
$('.myClass').removeClass('hidden');
```

У Bootstrap есть такой стандартный класс. Если же его не использовать, то нужно прописать в CSS файле, который виден всегда и везде, данное свойство: .hidden{display:none;}, и юзать его где нужно.

Comment: если уж jQuery, то методы `.hide()/.show()`, Откуда взялся класс `.hidden`?

Comment: ну скорее всего я у себя прописал в css файле такой класс и использую его где нужно типа .hidden{display:none;}

Comment: хотя нет, я только что посмотрел, это стандартный класс bootstrap

Comment: Т.е. для вашего ответа нужно подключить bootstrap? Стоит указать это в ответе.

Comment: в моём случае этот класс стандартный. Но что мешает написать свой такой класс как я прописал чуть выше?

Comment: Я только лишь сказал, что из ответа не очевидно, что делает класс. Добавьте css